How do I specify a custom executable when running a CMake project in Visual Studio Code?
I'm working on a CMake project in Visual Studio Code that's cross-compiling for another platform. Consequently when I whack a keystroke to execute the command "CMake: Run Without Debugging" it attempts to launch an executable that can't be run on the host system and fails.
I've written a script that will execute the project's output in an emulated environment, so when I use my keyboard shortcut to run, I just want it to execute that script. But so far I can't figure out how to do that!
Is there a setting somewhere that lets me specify exactly which executable will be executed either a) when I type the keystroke to run my project, or b) when Visual Studio Code executes the "CMake: Run Without Debugging" command?

After quite a lot of searching around, it became clear to me that I'm going against the grain in how Visual Studio Code wants to work, and there doesn't seem to be a good direct way to do this. The main sticking point is that VS Code always wants to launch a task through a debugger, even when you pick the "Run without Debugging" either for CMake or for a launch task. Being that I'm cross-compiling (and for an archaic target at that), there is no debugger I can use!
So that means I have to hack it. I created a task for my workspace that runs my script, and then set up a keystroke that would execute it but only in my workspace by using the information in this excellent answer describing how to configure a workspace-only keystroke in spite of the fact that the VS Code devs seem to think workspace-specific keyboard shortcuts are a bad idea even though there are important use cases for them, such as mine. (But I digress.)
So my solution was (with names changed to keep things general):

Add the following to settings in my .code-workspace file:
"workspaceKeybindings.MyWorkspaceCustomRunTask.enabled": true

Added the follow entry into my workspace's task.json / tasks:


{
    "label" : "Run My Project",
    "type" : "shell",
    "command" : "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/my-custom-run-script.sh",
    "dependsOn": ["CMake: build"]
}


Added the following entry to my user-level keybindings.json:

{ 
    "key": "cmd+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Run My Project",
    "when": "config.workspaceKeybindings.MyWorkspaceCustomRunTask.enabled"
}

That did the trick.
I'm going to leave this question open in the hopes that a better and more direct solution comes along some day.

there's a cmake.debugConfig setting, but I really don't know if it can help you here and I suspect it can't. see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md.
